# Get coupon / Discount object

Tags: magento2, cart, coupon

In (themePath)/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml, i want get the coupon / Discount object.
I use this code :

```
@var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $block
[...]
var_dump($block->getCouponCode());
```

In a cart with a coupon/discount, the var_dump return NULL, why?

Anybody have a solution to get the coupon/discount object set with coupon/discount value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the coupon code directly from that template, you can try

```
$block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you Nikolas.